# Apple ID password nightmare

Tags: itunes, icloud, apple-id

We have checked a email saying his Apple ID password was changed. At 3:30 pm, I was reading Reddit about iPhone making calls its own, this afternoon I was reading issues about iPhone calls. At 5 pm I was watching YouTube around 5 pm, I was listening to Apple Music for free

Alright, I got the email saying my Apple ID was used to sign in to iCloud account but i didn’t do it! I was playing Fortnite, all of sudden i received an message from dad saying just told you the time, replied

I was waiting until dinner

What can you do?

Answer (score 3):

**This sounds like a [phishing attempt](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/security/business/security-101/what-is-phishing?ef_id=cf789a9ed6ed1a37649ef9348e45b1eb:G:s&OCID=AIDcmmdamuj0pc_SEM_cf789a9ed6ed1a37649ef9348e45b1eb:G:s&msclkid=cf789a9ed6ed1a37649ef9348e45b1eb)**.

Basically, an attacker sends you an email telling you that your account was compromised and provide you a link to logon to a spoofed page to capture your login credentials.

You will want to sign into iCloud.  If you can get in, it is likely your credentials were not compromised.  In any event, change the password and enable [two factor authentication](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204915) (2FA) for more security.

Most importantly, don’t reply to the email or click on any of the links.  If you did, change your password immediately!  If you check the email “From” address, it likely didn’t come from Apple.  If they provided a link, check the URL; if it doesn’t go to the apple.com domain, it’s a definite sign of a phishing attempt.

Comment: I want to underscore the importance of not trusting links you get in an email message. There are ways to make a URL *look* like it's going to apple.com (or some other legitimate domain), but actually go somewhere else. It's also possible to spoof the "From:" address in an email message. For safety, it's important to type the URL into your browser manually. appleid.apple.com and icloud.com are good places to go to verify your account, change passwords, set up 2FA, etc.

Comment: Going to appleid.apple.com and signing in is great because it will alert you if there's a problem with your account